# Jquery/Javascript using wrong IP in GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm coding a website, with `Isotope` and `InfiniteScroll`.

Once the content on the `index.php` has been scrolled through, content from the `1.php` is parsed and loaded in via `infinite-scroll.js`. Then from the `1.php` page, the second block of content is loaded in; from `2.php`.

Before the 2nd page loads in, I get an error in the console saying the following; `GET http://192.168.3.30/path-to-website/1.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` **BUT** the IP for this locally hosted website is `192.168.`**2**`.30`.

Why is it changing the IP, which I'm guessing is causing the time out error?

All code can be found below;

**index.php**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>TITLE</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


  <?php include 'db/db.php'; $query='SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 9' ; $result=mysql_query($query) or die($myQuery. "<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); $rows=mysql_num_rows($result); ?>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row nav">
      <div class="button-group filters-button-group">

        <div class="col-xs-5 nav-left"><a class="nav-link" data-filter=".folder-open">PROJECTS</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a class="nav-link" data-filter=".desktop">SERVICES</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a class="nav-link" href="blog.php">BLOG</a>
        </div>

        <a data-filter="*">
          <div class="col-xs-2"><span class="nav-logo center-block"></span>
          </div>
        </a>

        <div class="col-xs-5 nav-right"><a class="nav-link" data-filter=".user">PEOPLE</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a class="nav-link" data-filter=".briefcase">CLIENTS</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a class="nav-link" href="http://192.168.2.30/~ryanelliott/tonyg/contact">CONTACT</a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="heading">
        <h2>TAG LINE</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <section id="content">
      <div id="container" class="variable-sizes clearfix infinite-scrolling">
        <div class="grid">
          <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
          <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
          <?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { if ($row[ 'homepage-desc'] !='NULL' ) { echo '<div class="grid-item '.$row[ 'icon']. ' '.$row[ 'icon']. ' grid-item--'. $row[ 'card'] . '" data-category="'.$row[ 'icon']. '"> 
                        <div>
                            <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><div class="image"><img src="'. $row[ 'image-1'] . '" alt=""></div></a>
                            <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><h5 class="hold">'. $row[ 'title'] . '<i class="icon fa fa-'. $row[ 'icon'] . '"></i></h5></a>
                            <p class="light">'. $row[ 'homepage-desc'] . '</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>'; } else { echo '<div class="grid-item '.$row[ 'icon']. ' grid-item--'. $row[ 'card'] . '" data-category="'.$row[ 'icon']. '"> 
                            <div>
                                <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><div class="image"><img src="'. $row[ 'image-1'] . '" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><h5 class="holdfalse">'. $row[ 'title'] . '<i class="icon fa fa-'. $row[ 'icon'] . '"></i></h5></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>'; } } ?>

        </div>
      </div>

      <nav id="page">
        <a href="http://192.168.2.30/path-to-website/1.php">NEXT</a>
      </nav>


      <div class="push"></div>
      <div class="push"></div>
      <div class="push"></div>
      <div class="push"></div>


      <footer>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
              <p>footer info</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right right-fix">
              <p>secondary footer info</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/infinite-scroll-master/infinitescroll.min.js"></script>

        <script>
          $(function() {

            var $container = $('#container');

            $container.isotope({
              itemSelector: '.grid-item',
              percentPosition: true,
              masonry: {
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
              }
            });

            $container.infinitescroll({
                navSelector: '#page', // selector for the paged navigation 
                nextSelector: '#page a', // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
                itemSelector: '.grid-item', // selector for all items you'll retrieve
                debug: true,
                loading: {
                  finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
                  img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
                }
              },
              // call Isotope as a callback
              function(newElements) {
                $container.isotope('appended', $(newElements));
              }
            );


          });
        </script>

      </footer>
      <section>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**1.php** 
NOTE: the `2.php` is an exact copy of this, just with the next link changed to `3.php`.

```html
<?php include '../db/db.php'; $rand=r and(); $query='SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY RAND(' .$rand. ') LIMIT 9'; $result=m ysql_query($query) or die($myQuery. "<br/><br/>".mysql_error()); ?>
<section id="content">
  <div id="container" class="variable-sizes clearfix infinite-scrolling">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
      <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
      <?php while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { if ($row[ 'homepage-desc'] !='NULL' ) { echo '<div class="grid-item '.$row[ 'icon']. ' '.$row[ 'icon']. ' grid-item--'. $row[ 'card'] . '" data-category="'.$row[ 'icon']. '"> 
                        <div>
                            <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><div class="image"><img src="'. $row[ 'image-1'] . '" alt=""></div></a>
                            <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><h5 class="hold">'. $row[ 'title'] . '<i class="icon fa fa-'. $row[ 'icon'] . '"></i></h5></a>
                            <p class="light">'. $row[ 'homepage-desc'] . '</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>'; } else { echo '<div class="grid-item '.$row[ 'icon']. ' grid-item--'. $row[ 'card'] . '" data-category="'.$row[ 'icon']. '"> 
                            <div>
                                <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><div class="image"><img src="'. $row[ 'image-1'] . '" alt=""></div></a>
                                <a href="'.$row[ 'type']. '.php?id='. $row[ 'home_id'] . '"><h5 class="holdfalse">'. $row[ 'title'] . '<i class="icon fa fa-'. $row[ 'icon'] . '"></i></h5></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>'; } } ?>

    </div>
  </div>

  <nav id="page">
    <a href="http://192.168.2.30/path-to-website/2.php">NEXT</a>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: Could it be that some dirty jQuery code replaces every "2." in the *<a>* tag with the next increment and it just happens to target part of the IP accidentally?

Comment: @Robert Is there a quick way to search though the jQuery code to find a problem like this? Or is it just a case of scrolling through?